# How to sort and subset data in r

Tags: r

I am trying to sort a row based on the first letters of the cells and i am having hard time to write a code in r.

| snp | allele1 | allele2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mmsoop | A | A |
| rs3122 | C | G |
| SNP1234 | T | C |
| rs3144 | A | A |

The above is the example dataset to show how my dataset looks like and i want to subset the whole table based on snp row where the snp column starts with "rs" and "SNP"

Expected table:

| snp | allele1 | allele2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rs3122 | C | G |
| SNP1234 | T | C |
| rs3144 | A | A |

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively,

```r
df<- read.table(
  text= "
snp allele1 allele2
mmsoop  A   A
rs3122  C   G
SNP1234 T   C
rs3144  A   A",
  header=T
)

df[grep("^(SNP|rs)",df$snp),]

     snp allele1 allele2
2  rs3122       C       G
3 SNP1234       T       C
4  rs3144       A       A
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `grepl` in `subset` to create a logical vector by matching the `rs` or (`|`) `SNP` from the start (`^`) of the string to subset the rows

```
subset(df1, grepl("^(rs|SNP)", snp))
      snp allele1 allele2
2  rs3122       C       G
3 SNP1234       T       C
4  rs3144       A       A
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(snp = c("mmsoop", "rs3122", "SNP1234", "rs3144"
), allele1 = c("A", "C", "T", "A"), allele2 = c("A", "G", "C", 
"A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could combine `filter` with `str_detect`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(snp, 'rs|SNP'))
```

```
      snp allele1 allele2
1  rs3122       C       G
2 SNP1234       T       C
3  rs3144       A       A
```